# Получить файл непосредственно в скрипт

Tags: php

Есть страница php с формой, где выбирается файл (эксель) и передается в скрипт-обработчик, где в скрипте-обработчике его можно получить так:

```
$_FILES["file"]["name"]
```

Как можно получить файл сразу в скрипт-обработчик без формы? Т.е. получить файл, к примеру, в переменную, прямо по ходу работы скрипта-обработчика, без загрузки его через форму.
Файл находится в корне со страницей скриптом-обработчиком.

Спасибо.

Comment: `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В PHP не слишком силен, но правильно ли я понимаю, что через функцию file_get_contents() содержимое файла Эксель будет получено в строку? Мне же необходимо получить файл Эксель, чтобы далее его можно было обработать при помощи библиотеки PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: хотите сказать,что у библиотеки. работающей с эксель файлами нет методов для открытия файлов, ии что?

Comment: Что значит "без формы"? В показанном вами примере php-кода и так нету никакой формы. Вопрос непонятен

Comment: Если речь о  PhpSpreadsheet то вот в документации все описано: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/